# How to modify a specific script of a source code of R library before or after installation?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I am using a R library to estimate drought indices.

Here, I found an error in one of the script of the source code. I tried to refer all the relevant question regarding editing R package in windows using R Studio but could not get any help.

My question is, if I have downloaded the R source code from CRAN, how can I installed it after doing the required modification in the problematic script in Windows environment.

Comment: Is it  available on GitHub? If yes, you can fork it to your account, fix the codes, then use `devtools::install_github` to install it

Comment: No, I have downloaded the code from CRAN.

Comment: There are many tutorials on how to build and install packages locally. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: @mt1022 I tried to go through many answer posted on stackoverflow, but could not understand. I have stated my problem, i would highly appreciate if you could share something which fits here.

Comment: After revision, you can run `R CMD build pkgdir` to build the package and then `R CMD install` to install it. Questions are supposed to be reproducible, show where you get stuck so that others can give more helpful comments.

Comment: You can either use `R CMD INSTALL ...` on the command line as mentioned by @mt1022 or use `devtools::install(<pkgdir>)` within R.

Comment: @RalfStubner thanks it works. I used `devtools::install(<pkgdir>)` in R studio in Windows.